# Small note (i.e. footnotesize) below figure

Tags: floats, notes

I want to include a small note (i.e. footnotesize) below a figure. How do I do that? If I use caption, the note has a caption size and interferes with my caption.

Comment: You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: Is the "note" a simple legend to the figure or is it a footnote (and, if so, where would the footnote mark go)? May it have the full width of the text block, or should the width of the note match the width of the figure it refers to?

Comment: I think the salient point here is that there is nothing magical about typesetting within a figure environment. Just declare the approprate style(s) and type away.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen - The OP appears to need some help with the "declaring the appropriate style(s)" part of the job...

Comment: It's not a legend, but a small item of text below the caption where I can write a few notes that I do not wish to include in the main body of my text.

Comment: Right now, I write this:

\begin{tablenotes}
\item[Note] \textit{Notes:} The parameters of the model are evaluated at the means of the posterior distributions. The structural shock do not sum to the output gap and the unemployment rate since all initial values effects are left out of the plots, and since the model unemployment rate is an affine mapping of the actual unemployment rate plotted above. The contribution of measurement error innovations is for all practical purposes zero.
\end{tablenotes}

Comment: After the caption and before "\end{figure}". The problem is that to the left, the text ends when the figure ends; while to the right, the text ends when the text width of the main body ends.

@Mico: I would like the text block to have the width of the figure.

Comment: And the figure, is it inserted with `\includegraphics`? Do you specify a width, or do you just use the natural width of the graphics?

Comment: Maybe what you want is to set the figure, caption and notes in a `\parbox` (or `minipage`) of the same width as the figure. Then center the whole `\parbox`.

Comment: Thanks! I am doing this:

 \caption{Historical shock decomposition during 2007Q1-2012Q4}
\tiny
\\footnotesize
\parbox[b][4em][t]{0.95\textwidth}{\textit{Notes:} TEKST TEKST TEKST TEKST TEKST}
\end{figure}

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To have the legend occupy the same width as the associated graph, one may encase both in a `minipage` environment, as is done in the following MWE (minimum working example). Note the use of `\par` at the end of the footnote-sized material. Without the `\par` directive -- or a trailing blank line, which is the functional equivalent of a paragraph break in Tex -- you'd get the smaller font size but the wider line spacing that's appropriate for the document's normal font size.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % leave off '[demo]' in real document
\begin{document}
\hrule
(this rule just demonstrates the width of the textblock\dots)

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} % choose width suitably
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{mygraphicfile}
{\footnotesize Here are some notes that go with the graph. Here are some 
notes that go with the graph. Here are some notes that go with the graph. 
Here are some notes that go with the graph.\par}
\end{minipage}
\caption{Historical shock decomposition, 2007Q1--2012Q4}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If you want the explanatory stuff to go *after* the caption, you could place it in its own separate `minipage` environment, taking care to give it the same width as the graph. (I know there's no arguing about taste, but to me placing the explanatory stuff that far away from the graph doesn't look right.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % leave off '[demo]' in real document
\begin{document}
\hrule
(this rule just demonstrates the width of the textblock\dots)

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.65\textwidth]{mygraphicfile}
\caption{Historical shock decomposition, 2007Q1--2012Q4}

\medskip % induce some separation between caption and explanatory material
\begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} % choose width suitably
{\footnotesize Here are some notes that go with the graph. Here are some notes that go with the graph. Here are some notes that go with the graph. Here are some notes that go with the graph.\par}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice! But I think the OP wants the notes to be "After the caption and before "\end{figure}""

Comment: @KevinC - Thanks for pointing this out. I'll post a second MWE.

Comment: "width=0.65\textwidth"  What are the units in 0.65 ?

Comment: @user46548 - `0.65\textwidth` means "65 percent of the width of the text block". The units are immaterial, in the sense that it doesn't matter whether the parameter `\textwidth` was specified in `cm`, `in`, or any other valid length unit that TeX recognizes. (AFAICT, "parsec" is not recognized by TeX...)

Answer (score 4):

Here even `\tiny`, not only `\footnotesize` :-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{it}

{\tiny I want to include a small note (i.e. footnotesize) below a figure. How do I do that? If I use caption, the note has a caption size and interferes with my caption.}
\caption{Normal text }
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: actually, `\tiny` is too tiny.  `\footnotesize` is the usual size, even within a figure.

Answer (score 1):

`\scriptsize` may work for you: it is between `\tiny` and `\footnotesize`
(from https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Font_sizes,_families,_and_styles)

Hope this helps :)